# Data structure for expandable 3D array?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure similar to `T[,,]` (a 3D array) except I don't know the dimensions beforehand (nor have a reasonable upper bound) that will expand outwards as time goes on. I'd like to use negative indexes as well.

The only thing that comes to mind is a dictionary, with some kind of `Point3` struct as the key. Are there any other alternatives? I'd like to lookups to be as fast as possible. The data will always be clustered around `0,0,0`. It can expand in any direction, but there will never be any "gaps" between points.

---

I think I'm going to go ahead and just use a `Dictionary<Point3, T>` for now, and see how that performs. If it's a performance issue I'll try building a wrapper around `T[,,]` such that I can use negative indexes.

Comment: You're asking for an N-Dimensional array (that you don't know the dimensions of until runtime)? What do you plan to do with this array? What makes you believe an array is the correct data-structure for your problem?

Comment: @ProgrammingHero: Specifically 3-dimensional. I was thinking an array because fast lookup times are crucial. Now that I think about it more though, I think I'm going to have to eventually unload data (it'll get too big), so the "center" of the data may shift away from 0,0,0. It's for a game, and it may be called thousands or millions of times per second.

Comment: Can you tell a little more about the context your problem occurs? Also are there any nonstandart operations you need to support, i.e. range queries?

Comment: @Ali: It's for storing world data for a game. I need to keep objects near the player in memory. I'm storing them in Chunks, so I want a quick lookup to find these chunks. I wasn't planning on supporting range queries, but if there's some magically efficient way to find "Chunks within a radius of 10 from X,Y,Z" that would be wicked.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you'll need to store this in a data structure resembling a sparse array, because you have no idea how large your data-set is going to be. So a Dictionary seems reasonable.

I'm going a little crazy here, but I think your indices should be in [Spherical Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). It makes sense to me as your data grows outwards. It will also make finding elements at a specific range from (0, 0, 0) extremely easy.

Comment: I've used polar coordinates before, but I never thought about extending that to 3D. I don't think it would work very well though, because my data is too "blocky"; i.e., lengths and angles don't work so well with integer coordinates.

Comment: Hmmm, you could convert them to integer angles and lengths. You'll get spherical blocks, though. I don't think the conversion will be too painful - certainly less than the O(logn) of adding a node to a balanced KD-tree.

Comment: Okay, lets say the block directly to the right of me is (1,0,0) where "1" is the length of the vector, and (0,0) are the two angles. Then what would the block diagonally in front of me be? It's a distance of sqrt(2), and 45 degrees on one of the angles. How would you represent that as an integer? I *could* use floats and round it off, but I suspect that some blocks will get missed completely, especially when they're further away.

Comment: The block in front of you diagonally will not be in a distance of sqrt(2), but rather everything between 1 and 2 away from you, at an angle between (for example) 10 and 15 degrees horizontally, and 20 and 25 degrees vertically. You'll use integer distances and angles.

Answer (score 2):

If you may need range queries, KD-Trees comes to mind. They are tree-like structures, at each level seperate the universe into two along one axis. They offer O(logN) lookup time (for constant number of dimensions) which may or may not be fast enough, but they also provide O(logN + S) time for range queries where S is the size of the items found, which usually is very good. They can handle dynamic data (insertions and deletions along with lookups) but the tree may become unbalanced as a result. Also you can do Nearest Neighboor search from a given point, (i.e. get the 10 nearest objects to point (7,8,9)) Wikipedia, as always, is a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree

If there are huge numbers of things in the world, of if the world is very dynamic (things move, be created/destroyed all the time), kd-trees may not be good enough. If most of the time you will only ask "give me the thing at (7,8,9)" you can either use a hash as you mentioned in your question or something like a `List<List<List<T>>>`. I'd just implement whichever is easier within an interface and worry about the performance later.

Comment: I'm thinking the KD-tree will be too slow. I'll start with a Dictionary first I guess, because that's easy.

Answer (score 1):

I am kind of assuming you need the dynamic aspect because array could be huge. In that case, what you could try is to allocate your array as a set of 3d 'tiles'. At the top level you have a 3d data structure that stores pointers to your tiles. You expand and allocate this as you go along.

Each individual tile could contain, say, 32x32x32 voxels. Or whatever amount suits your goals. 
Looking up you tile is done by dividing your coordinate index by 32 (by bitshifting, of course), and the index in the tile is calculated by masking away the upper bits.

A lookup like this is fairly cheap, possible on par with a .net Dictionary, but it will use less memory, which is good for performance too.

The resulting array will be chunky, though: the array boundaries are multiples of your tile size.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing actually. I was secretly asking about how I should store the chunks of tiles though; the 'tiles' themselves will just be 32x32x32 arrays. i.e., what data structure do I hold the pointers in?

Comment: Well, I guess great minds think alike. But anyway, how many tiles do you need? Thousands? You could use a traditional array to store the tiles and copy it to a bigger array as needed. Even if you have millions of tiles, copying to a bigger array should be quite fast. I don't suppose you need to do this for every frame....

Comment: I've got it rendering with close to a million tiles, but it's getting laggy. The more I can support the better. I might try building a wrapper around a traditional array so I can access it with negative indices...but I'll try a dict first and see how that performs.

Answer (score 1):

Array access is a very fast linear lookup - if speed of lookup is your priority, then it's probably the way to go, depending on how often you will need to modify your arrays.

If your goal is to maintain the chunks around a player, you might want to arrange a "current world" array structure around the player, such that it is a 3-dimensional array with the centre chunk at `9,9,9` with a size of `[20,20,20]`. Each time the player leaves the centre chunk for another, you re-index the array to drop the old chunks and move on.

Ultimately, you're asking for options on how to optimize your game engine, but it's nearly impossible to say which is going to be correct for you. Even though games tend to be more optimized for performance than other applications, don't get lured into micro-optimizations; optimize for **readability** first and then optimize for performance when you find it necessary.

If you suspect this particular data-structure is going to be a bottleneck in your engine, put some performance tracing in so it's easy to be sure one way or the other once you've got the engine running.

Comment: I know the woes of premature optimization, but I've already got something running, and I'm hitting the max already, and I've barely implemented any features. Re-indexing the array sounds costly. Wouldn't it be better to build a wrapper around a `T[,,]` such that the center can shift around transparently? i.e., `0,0,0` might not map to `T[0,0,0]` but some other index, depending on where the center is? Then I can allocate a much larger array, say 100x100x100, and center it around 50,50,50, and maybe only use up 10x10x10, but I won't have to reindex until it shifts off the edge...

Comment: This is why it's a call only you have the information to make; if you re-index every time the centre changes, you have to update 8000 references each time this event occurs. If you go via an abstraction, you must apply a coordinate transformation every time you do a lookup in the matrix. I can't tell you which will be faster without knowing your engine as well as you do; even then, I'd want to benchmark both options.

Comment: It's worth adding: Your problem might be that you're making a lot of direct lookups. Have you considered ways to reduce the number?

Comment: I'd have to perform a coordinate transformation regardless; the only question is whether I let the extra layer of abstraction do it for me, or if I do it before I perform the lookup. I'm going to try to minimize the number of lookups...not quite sure how everything is going to pan out just yet :)